# Angular 8/9 How to disable buttons dynamically that were also created dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular9

So I have a project where I had sets of buttons created dynamically. Each set has two buttons, and when one is clicked it's collapsible content appears. If you click the other button in the set, the first button's content disappears, and the second button's content appears. (For the sake of brevity I figured I'd exclude the content). The total sets can be determined by simply changing the value of a variable called totalSetsOfButtons. Right now, it is set to the number 8, so there will be eight sets of two buttons.

In the first button's collapsible content, there is an image upload that the user can interact with. If the user interacts with this, I want the second button to disable. When the user loads an image, a variable called `isImageAdded` is switched from `null` to `true`, which tells the `disabled` attribute to trigger in the second button as you can see below. The problem is, if an image is added, this disables ALL of the second buttons in every set.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of totalSetsOfButtons; let i = index">
  <h5 class="set-num">Set #{{i+1}}</h5>

  <div class="set-btns">
    <div class="set{{i}}-btn1" id="set-btn1">
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-light question-btn1" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#collapseExample' + i" aria-expanded="false" [attr.aria-controls]="collapseExample1"> Add New Question
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="set{{i}}-btn2" id="set-btn2">
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-light question{{i}}-btn2" [disabled]="isImageAdded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" [attr.data-target]="'#collapseExample2' + i" aria-expanded="false"
                        [attr.aria-controls]="collapseExample2">Add Pre-existing Question
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I only disable the second button in the set the user is interacting with? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If every second button is get disabled then your scope is not inside one set, check your code which is disabling the button

Comment: Can we have other part of your code? js code?

Comment: Can you post and image showing your buttons set (just want to see hierarchy) or if you can set up stackblitz and we can see the code. We would be able to help you much better?

Comment: @WahabShah Just a sec, I'll set up a stackblitz!

Comment: @DupinderSingh ^^^

Comment: @WahabShah sorry for the wait, I haven't used stackblitz much. The view of the app is a tad wonky, as this is supposed to show up in a modal window. Also not sure how to get the buttons to expand the content but the code is there: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bqkr8e?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: @DupinderSingh ^^^ again

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have set the [disabled] property to **isImageAdded** which is a global property in the component. So setting it to true/false will affect the disabled state of all the buttons bound to it.

In it's place, you might prefer to set a variable in the **totalSetsOfButtons** array, and use that to enable/disable the corresponding button.

For example:

```
totalSetsOfButtons = [
  { ...yourEarlierArgs, isImageAdded: false },
  { ...yourEarlierArgs, isImageAdded: false },
  ... more 6 similar items
];
```

And when you interact with the application, you can update the value of the isImageAdded in the array item, and use it.

```
<button [disabled]="item.isImageAdded">Add Pre-existing Question</button>
```